# OpenCMIS Download

Tags: content-management-system, cmis

It looks like OpenCMIS is the best java lib for CMIS integration (according to this forum!).  I can't download the source (stuck behind a firewall)- is there a (client) JAR bundle available for download, anywhere???  Thanks, Gavin

Comment: If you can't download the source, how can you download the JAR?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no bundle yet. There is no official release of OpenCMIS at the moment.

If you're brave and persistent you can collect all the OpenCMIS Jars (without dependencies) [from the build server](https://hudson.apache.org/hudson/view/Chemistry/job/Chemistry%20-%20OpenCMIS%20-%20install/lastSuccessfulBuild/).

Or, you grab the the [OpenCMIS Swing Client](https://hudson.apache.org/hudson/view/Chemistry/job/Chemistry%20-%20OpenCMIS%20-%20install/lastSuccessfulBuild/) and extract all the Jars you need (with dependencies).

Florian